# How to organize two git repos for CI

Tags: git, go, module, continuous-integration

I have a git repo "core" and "project" repo, that is using "core" as dependency. If I want to change some API of "core" module, and its usages in "project", I create two separate pull requests in gitlab. But our continuous integration system can't test "project" until "core" will be merged, if "core" contains API changes.
What I want, is the possibility of "project" test will go on the same branch in "core". For example if I created branches "feature-42" in "project" and "core", the "project" tests will start on the "feature-42" branch of "core".

Now we have an opportunity to move at go modules, but it is hard to always specify the direct commit hash in go.mod file(many possibilities to made a mistake).
It looks like we should use monorepo, but I scared of the possibility our project will become monolith (considering that we have not very qualified developers).

How can we organize our continuous integration?

P.S. also we don't wanna use tags with version, because people works in parallel, and it is hard to maintain always non-decreasing versions.

Comment: There are many ways to address this issue, which makes it too broad to adequately answer here. Also, none of them relate specifically to Go, meaning if you find a solution on Google for any language, you can adapt it to Go. You should do some research. Read blog posts and forum discussions about the different approaches, and choose one you're comfortable with.

Comment: Usually I will do it with git-submodules, but it is not a go way because of gopath and go organisation, so, I disagree with you.

Comment: You can have your submodules mounted under, or linked to `vendor`, so your disagreement is actually wrong.

Comment: Although I strongly discourage submodules for such a thing anyway.

Comment: The above comments seem to be confusing Go modules with Git submodules. The question seems clearly about the former, not the latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `go.mod` file can specify an explicit commit of a dependency — even if that commit is on a branch! — as long as the commit has actually been published to that repository.

So if you publish a feature on the `feature-42` branch of `core` and want to use that in `project`, you can run `go get core@feature-42` within the `project` module and you should get a version that includes that feature.

(The `go` command knows how to resolve a branch name to a specific commit in general, so you shouldn't need to name the commit hash explicitly. However, the `go.mod` file will record a [pseudo-version](https://tip.golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Pseudo_versions) with the resolved hash.)

---

As another alternative, you could add a `go mod edit -replace` command to your CI system, to have it explicitly replace the selected version of the `core` module with the branch in question.

---

All that said, it sounds like it would probably be simpler for you to switch to a monorepo, perhaps with a single `go.mod` file at the repo root so that everything is versioned in lock-step. In my experience, the best way to avoid a Go project turning into a monolith is through the use of [`internal` packages](https://golang.org/doc/go1.4#internalpackages), not separate repositories.